# print a column instead of list in python matrix

Tags: python, list, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have a text file like this:

```
abc 4   2   3   4   1   4   1   2   3   3
abc 4   2   3   4   1   4   1   2   3   3
def 4   3   3   4   1   4   1   2   3   3
def 4   3   3   4   1   4   1   2   3   3
ghi 4   5   3   4   1   4   1   2   3   3
ghi 4   5   3   4   1   4   1   2   3   3
jkl 4   6   3   4   1   4   1   2   3   3
jkl 4   6   3   4   1   4   1   2   3   3
mno 4   8   3   4   1   4   1   2   3   3
mno 4   8   3   4   1   4   1   2   3   3
```

I want to randomly replace the data, from the columns, with 0 for the identifier given in column 1. Each identifier has two rows. I want to replace both the rows with 0 randomly. I am taking each column into a list, and picking up a random odd number, n desired times, and replacing that index and previous index with 0.

My code looks like

```
for i in range(1,11): #The file has 11 columns
    for line in open("structure.tsv",'r'):
        splitFile=line.strip().split("\t")
        temp_array.append(splitFile[i])
    for x in random.sample(range(1,10),3): #Replace values for any three identifiers randomly
        temp_array[x]=0
        temp_array[x-1]=0
    print temp_array
    temp_array=[]
```

I get output like:

```
[0, 0, '4', '4', '4', '4', 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, '5', '5', '6', '6', 0, 0]
['3', '3', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '3', '3']
['4', '4', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '4', '4']
[0, 0, '1', '1', '1', '1', 0, 0, 0, 0]
['4', '4', 0, 0, '4', '4', 0, 0, 0, 0]
['1', '1', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '1', '1']
[0, 0, '2', '2', 0, 0, 0, 0, '2', '2']
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '3', '3', '3', '3']
[0, 0, '3', '3', 0, 0, 0, 0, '3', '3']
```

but I want the output similar to that of the input file.

```
abc 0   0   3   4   0   4   1   0   0   0
abc 0   0   3   4   0   4   1   0   0   0
def 4   0   0   0   1   0   0   2   0   3
def 4   0   0   0   1   0   0   2   0   3
ghi 4   5   0   0   1   4   1   0   0   0
ghi 4   5   0   0   1   4   1   0   0   0
jkl 0   6   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   0
jkl 0   6   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   0
mno 0   0   3   4   0   0   0   2   3   3
mno 0   0   3   4   0   0   0   2   3   3
```

Comment: Will two lines with the same string ever have different numbers?

Comment: yes...the numbers may differ for an identifier....

Comment: Can you give us an example of exactly what you want your output to look like? I can't quite understand what final result you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this by taking a different approach to how you store and process the data.  Think dictionaries (or if order matters, [ordered dictionaris](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict))

Consider storing your data as follows:

```
data = {"abc":([list of first line of numbers],[list of second line of numbers]), and so on}
```

What you can then do randomly select three strings, and replace the first number of each list with zeros.

```
for key in randomelyChosenList:
    data[key][0][0] = 0
    data[key][1][0] = 0
```

This assures that both lines will both always be changed and will make writing your data back to the file a bit easier